# How to force the left hand of an equation against an equal sign?

Tags: equations

[image]

I can't find a proper way to force the left hand of the equalities on the second row of the first the equation to stick against the equal sign. Ideally, I would like something that looks like the second equation in terms of the alignment.

Here is the code I used for the first equation using in the LibreOffice extension for Latex:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
(x-2)(5-2x)=0 \quad &\Leftrightarrow \quad x-2&&=0 \quad &&\text{ou} \quad 5-2x&&=0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow \quad x&&=2 \quad &&\text{ou} \quad x&&=\frac{5}{2}
\end{alignat*}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site,  Your code has a compilation error, plus the fact that it is just a snippet and not a complete example starting with `\documentclass`.  Please edit

Comment: I am using a LibreOffice extension for Latex that will compile the code into an image, it is not a snippet. I think that the ```\documentclass``` is implemented through the GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `&` provides a `r`ight and `l`eft alignment point. That is, the content on the left of `&` is `r`ight aligned and the content to the right is `l`eft aligned. So, if something ends up being aligned on the wrong side you need to add or remove an `&` to change that:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
(x-2)(5-2x)= 0 \quad 
    &\Leftrightarrow \quad & x-2 & = 0 && \quad \text{ou} \quad &5-2x&=0 \\
    &\Leftrightarrow \quad &   x & = 2 && \quad \text{ou} \quad &x   &=\frac{5}{2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very well explained.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there is a proper way using `alignat`, but here, I use facilities of the `tabstackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\begin{document}
\[
\tabularCenterstack{rlrlcrl}{
(x-2)(5-2x)=0 \quad &\Leftrightarrow \quad& x-2&=0 \quad &\text{ou}& \quad 5-2x&=0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow  &x&=22 \quad &\text{ou}& \quad x&=\frac{5}{2}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]