# Spacing between two alignment "columns"

Tags: spacing, alignment, columns

I would like to make the red spacing the same as the blue, i.e. the spacing between two alignment "columns" to be a normal space. How can I do this?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}

\begin{document}
    $\begin{aligned}
        \hspace{1cm} &\Rightarrow (\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)\Rightarrow (\lambda-\lambda_3) &&\Rightarrow u=Ae^{\lambda_1 t}+Be^{\lambda_2 t}+Ce^{\lambda_3 t}\\
        &\Rightarrow (\lambda-\lambda_1)^2(\lambda-\lambda_2) &&\Rightarrow u=Ae^{\lambda_1 t}+Bte^{\lambda_1 t}+Ce^{\lambda_2 t}\\
    \end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: One way to control the spacing is to use `alignedat` instead.  Also, note that each `&` provides a `r`ight (content on the left) and `l`eft alignment point (content on the right.  Thus, you seems to have used extra `&` and not one at the second `\Rightarrow` where you want to control the spacing.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you for your answer ! Since I started using Latex, I've always had trouble understanding how the ```&``` symbol works in align environments. Do you know a manual that would help me understand how it works? I haven't found any on the internet yet.

Comment: There are numerous questions on this site that discuss that. For instance, see the recent question [How to force the left hand of an equation against an equal sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630558/4301) for instance.  If you want more details you can use `texdoc amsmath`.  An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode?lang=en).  It too had some diffculty, but as you do more TeXing, it should become clearer.